# How can I make raw sql ManyToMany and Annotation in django?

Tags: sql, django, annotate

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(FBUser, related_name='posts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts')

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(FBUser, related_name='comments')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='comments')

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I made this code, but this code is really slow to get result over 10 seconds.

```
_group.user_set.filter(posts__group=_group, comments__group=_group) \
            .annotate(p_count=Count('posts', distinct=True), c_count=Count('comments', distinct=True))
```

How can I make this code to raw sql?